# Tensorflow restoring model: attempting to use uninitialized value

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to restore my model in Tensorflow. This is how I saved the model:

```
ae = autoencoder(input_shape=[None, height, width, depth], conv_strides=[[1, stride1, stride1, 1], [1, stride2, stride2, 1]], n_filters=[1, num_filters, num_filters], filter_sizes=[size_filter, size_filter, size_filter], corruption=False, poolsize=2)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(ae['cost'])

# create a session to use the graph
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Network is trained here
    ...
    saver.save(sess, "model.ckpt")
```

Then I try to restore it using this code (in another file, after training the model, so in a seperate session):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model.ckpt.meta")
    saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored")
    ae = autoencoder(input_shape=[None, height, width, depth], conv_strides=[[1, stride1, stride1, 1], [1, stride2, stride2, 1]], n_filters=[1, num_filters, num_filters], filter_sizes=[size_filter, size_filter, size_filter], corruption=False, poolsize=2)
    # create stuff here to reconstruct images using the autoencoder
    ...
    recon = sess.run(ae['y'], feed_dict={ae['x']: batch})
```

It prints out that the model is restored, but I get an error:
 
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value
According to the Tensorflow documentation, you do not have to initialize the variables after restoring, so I guess it does not go wrong there. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have a feeling that I am doing something really stupid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ae = autoencoder(input_shape=[None, height, width, depth], conv_strides=
[[1, stride1, stride1, 1], [1, stride2, stride2, 1]], n_filters=[1, num_filters, num_filters], filter_sizes=[size_filter, size_filter, size_filter], corruption=False, poolsize=2)    
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(ae['cost'])

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored")
    # create stuff here to reconstruct images using the autoencoder
    ...
    recon = sess.run(ae['y'], feed_dict={ae['x']: batch})
```

Comment: To be clear, do I have to use `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model.ckpt.meta")` to create the saver? Because this does not work unfortunately.

Comment: My bad, see the modified version above.